# Mailgraph with regex for configuration

Tags: perl

MAILGRAPH MONITORING TOOL CONFIGURATION.

This tool generate graph for send / receive/ bounce/ reject/ spam/ virus mails
all graph are generating except spam and virus as my log file is differ than others

In one of the doc they use below regex for there log format

logformat :

```
Jan  8 03:15:26 mailtest amavis[12306]: (12306-14)   Blocked    SPAM ,
LOCAL [127.0.0.1] [69.95.139.186]  est.it> ->  xxx.fr>
, quarantine: spam/spam-Gca-eg8QanXu.gz  , Message-ID:
 sleeting>  , mail_id:
Gca-eg8QanXu , Hits: 22.996 , size: 21007 , Subject: "re:worth every
dollar" , Tests:
[BAYES_99=3.5,HTML_80_90=0.146,HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_24=0.502,HTML_MESSAGE=0.001,RAZOR2_CF_RANGE_51_100=0.056,RAZOR2_CHECK=1.511,RCVD_IN_BL_SPAMCOP_NET=1.216,RCVD_IN_DSBL=3.805,RCVD_IN_XBL=3.076,URIBL_JP_SURBL=2.462,URIBL_SBL=0.996,URIBL_SC_SURBL=4.263,URIBL_WS_SURBL=1.462]
, 3303 ms
```

Regex format :

```
if(   $text =~ /^\([0-9-]+\)\s+(Passed|Blocked)\s+SPAM\b/)
```

but this never suits to my log file. Can you pls help me to write regex which help me to generate spam and virus graphs. my log file is below

logformat:

```
May  3 20:23:42 mx2 amavisd: May  3 20:23:42 mx2.example.com /usr/sbin/amavisd[25190]: (25190-20) Passed SPAM, [217.11.177.26] [72.0.144.176]  -> , quarantine: spam-ehiWxkOBcaOO.gz, mail_id: ehiWxkOBcaOO, Hits: 40.024, size: 853, queued_as: 5EEF64770, 5211 ms
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Answer (score 1):

You are very close!  Try the following:

```
/\(([0-9-]+)\)\s+(Passed|Blocked)\s+SPAM\b/
```

This omits `^` since you don't want the match to start at the beginning of the line.  Also, it uses and escapes the parentheses, to capture the digits and dash.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot kenosis i can now find my spam / virus details from logs

Comment: @Kenosis- can u please help me in finding the way? From my file i want to replace single space with comma and don't want to touch any other space?

Comment: @user2074481 - I think it may be best to post this as a separate question along with some sample data so respondents can actually view the context of the single spaces and your desired output after the substitution.